# Keep the values after comma if it is not 0

Tags: php, explode, substr

I have following values

```
100,00
100,12
122,32
120,00
140,00
123,85
```

If there is 0 after comma like 100,00 then I need to have it like 100. But if it is 123,85 where there is no 0 after comma then I need to keep it as it like 123,85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `preg_replace` function:

```
$result = preg_replace("/,00$/", "", $input);
```

Change to `/(,00|0)$/` if you want to change `123,10` to `123,1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply match a `,` and a `0` afterwards and everything following it.

```
/(\,0.*)/
```

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$tests = [
        '100,00',
        '100,12',
        '122,32',
        '120,00',
        '140,00',
        '123,85'
    ];

foreach($tests as $test){
    echo $test," => ",preg_replace("/(\,0.*)/","",$test),PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/nMfcG